# KeyNotFoundException when execute proxygen in jni4net

Tags: java, c#, dll, jni4net

I realise an implementation to connect C# with Java through jni4net.

I generated a test class with C# ( conversion the cs file to dll) and called from Java, works fine.

My problem is with a dll; this dll was provided by the client. When executing the proxygen to generate files and put files in the workspace, throws this error:

[KeyNotFoudException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V00HD.png)

I'm not a .net developer, in my investigation of the exception, i find solutions, but in the code of dll can't find the error.

I use dotPeek and .Net Reflector to decompile dll.

This dll manage the system printers and print files.

Any suggest or idea about the exception?

thanks in advance.

this is dll code:

```
    // Decompiled with JetBrains decompiler
// Type: SymetryBusModuloImpresora.cImpresora
// Assembly: SymetryBusModuloImpresora, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
// MVID: 86BC466E-075C-4F92-BB07-DEADD34550EF

using System;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SymetryBusModuloImpresora
{
  public class cImpresora
  {
    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, int level, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct), In] cImpresora.DOCINFOA di);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, int dwCount, out int dwWritten);

    public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, int dwCount)
    {
      int dwWritten = 0;
      IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
      cImpresora.DOCINFOA di = new cImpresora.DOCINFOA();
      bool flag = false;
      di.pDocName = "BanCoppel PDF Print";
      di.pDataType = "RAW";
      if (cImpresora.OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
      {
        if (cImpresora.StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
        {
          if (cImpresora.StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
          {
            flag = cImpresora.WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
            cImpresora.EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
          }
          cImpresora.EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
        }
        cImpresora.ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
      }
      if (!flag)
        Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
      return flag;
    }

    public static bool PrinterExists(string printerName)
    {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(printerName))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("printerName");
      return PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Cast<string>().Any<string>((Func<string, bool>) (name => printerName.ToUpper().Trim() == name.ToUpper().Trim()));
    }

    public static bool SendFileToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szFileName)
    {
      FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open);
      BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader((Stream) fileStream);
      byte[] numArray = new byte[fileStream.Length];
      IntPtr num1 = new IntPtr(0);
      int int32 = Convert.ToInt32(fileStream.Length);
      byte[] source = binaryReader.ReadBytes(int32);
      IntPtr num2 = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(int32);
      int startIndex = 0;
      IntPtr destination = num2;
      int length = int32;
      Marshal.Copy(source, startIndex, destination, length);
      int num3 = cImpresora.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, num2, int32) ? 1 : 0;
      Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(num2);
      return num3 != 0;
    }

    public static bool SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
    {
      int length = szString.Length;
      IntPtr coTaskMemAnsi = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
      cImpresora.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, coTaskMemAnsi, length);
      Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(coTaskMemAnsi);
      return true;
    }

    public static int ImprimirPDF(string p_Ruta, string p_Archivo)
    {
      string path = p_Ruta + "\\" + p_Archivo;
      if (!File.Exists(path))
        return -7;
      try
      {
        byte[] source = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        string printerName = new PrinterSettings().PrinterName;
        IntPtr num1 = new IntPtr(0);
        int length1 = source.Length;
        IntPtr num2 = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(length1);
        int startIndex = 0;
        IntPtr destination = num2;
        int length2 = length1;
        Marshal.Copy(source, startIndex, destination, length2);
        cImpresora.SendBytesToPrinter(printerName, num2, length1);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(num2);
        return 0;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return -5;
      }
    }

    [STAThread]
    public static int ImpresoraEstatus(string p_Impresora)
    {
      int num = -2;
      new ManagementScope("\\root\\cimv2").Connect();
      foreach (ManagementObject managementObject in new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer").Get())
      {
        if (managementObject["Name"].ToString().Trim().ToLower().Equals(p_Impresora.ToLower()))
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Printer = " + managementObject["Name"]);
          if (managementObject["WorkOffline"].ToString().ToLower().Equals("true"))
          {
            Console.WriteLine("Your Plug-N-Play printer is not connected.");
            num = -8;
            break;
          }
          Console.WriteLine("Your Plug-N-Play printer is connected.");
          num = 0;
          break;
        }
      }
      return num;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class DOCINFOA
    {
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
      public string pDocName;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
      public string pOutputFile;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
      public string pDataType;
    }
  }
}
```

**Aditionally: I tried with JNI: 
I created a C++ file with reference to dll provided by the client and my implemetation is:**

The code C++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CppSymetryBusModuloImpresora.h"
#include "mx_com_solser_service_PrinterService.h"
#include <string>

using System::Text::Encoding;

String^ toString(const char * chars) {
    int len = (int)strlen(chars);
    array<unsigned char>^ a = gcnew array<unsigned char>(len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        a[i] = chars[i];
    }

    return Encoding::UTF8->GetString(a);
}


int imprimirPDF(const char *ruta, const char *archivo) {
    return SymetryBusModuloImpresora::cImpresora::ImprimirPDF(toString(ruta), toString(archivo)); //Accesing to dll method
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_mx_com_solser_service_PrinterService_imprimirPDF
(JNIEnv *env, jclass c, jstring ruta, jstring archivo) {
    jint responseCode;
    jboolean isCopyRuta;
    jboolean isCopyArchivo;

    const char *p_ruta = env->GetStringUTFChars(ruta, &isCopyRuta);
    const char *p_archivo = env->GetStringUTFChars(archivo, &isCopyArchivo);
    responseCode = imprimirPDF(p_ruta, p_archivo);

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(ruta, p_ruta);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(archivo, p_archivo);

    return responseCode;
}
```

Java code:

```
package mx.com.solser.service;


import mx.com.solser.exception.PrinterException;
import mx.com.solser.util.CodigoError;

public class PrinterService  {

    private Integer codigoRespuesta = -1;
    private static PrinterService printerService = null;
    private static final String SPACE_FORMAT = "Codigo Respuesta: %d ::: %s";

    static native int imprimirPDF(String ruta, String archivo);

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("CppSymetryBusModuloImpresora");
    }

    private PrinterService () {}

    public static PrinterService getInstance() {
        return printerService != null ? printerService : new PrinterService();
    }

    public Integer printAndGetCode(final String ruta, final String archivo) throws PrinterException {
        if (isNullOrEmpty(ruta) || isNullOrEmpty(archivo))
            throw new PrinterException(getMessageCode(codigoRespuesta, CodigoError.getMessage(codigoRespuesta)));       

        if ((codigoRespuesta = imprimirPDF(ruta, archivo)) != 0)
            throw new PrinterException(getMessageCode(codigoRespuesta, CodigoError.getMessage(codigoRespuesta)));

        return codigoRespuesta;
    }   

    private boolean isNullOrEmpty(String param) {
        return (param == null || param.isEmpty());
    }

    private String getMessageCode(final Integer codigoRespuesta, final String message) {
        return String.format(SPACE_FORMAT, codigoRespuesta, message);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (0xe0434352), pid=1472, tid=0x000000000000186c
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_112-b15) (build 1.8.0_112-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.112-b15 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0x2a1c8]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: E:\WSImpresion\PrintService\hs_err_pid1472.mdmp
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# E:\WSImpresion\PrintService\hs_err_pid1472.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

LOG:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (0xe0434352), pid=7776, tid=0x0000000000003128
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_112-b15) (build 1.8.0_112-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.112-b15 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0x2a1c8]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: E:\WSImpresion\PrintService\hs_err_pid7776.mdmp
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000002ccd800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=12584, stack(0x0000000002cd0000,0x0000000002dd0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xe0434352, ExceptionInformation=0xffffffff80070002 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x00007fff4ee40000 

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000f8aaf0, RBX=0x0000000002dcc230, RCX=0x0000000000000000, RDX=0x0000000000f768d0
RSP=0x0000000002dca2b0, RBP=0x0000000002dca960, RSI=0x0000000002dcc860, RDI=0x0000000002dcb0c0
R8 =0x0000000200000000, R9 =0x0000000100000002, R10=0x0000000000000002, R11=0x0000000100000002
R12=0x0000000002dca408, R13=0x0000000000000000, R14=0x0000000002dcb6d8, R15=0x0000000000000000
RIP=0x00007fff77b0a1c8, EFLAGS=0x0000000000000206

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0000000002dca2b0)
0x0000000002dca2b0:   00000001e06d7363 0000000002dcc230
0x0000000002dca2c0:   0000000002dcc860 0000000002dcb0c0
0x0000000002dca2d0:   00000001e0434352 0000000000000000
0x0000000002dca2e0:   00007fff77b0a1c8 0000000000000005
0x0000000002dca2f0:   ffffffff80070002 0000000000000000
0x0000000002dca300:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000002dca310:   00007fff4ee40000 0000000000000000
0x0000000002dca320:   0000000000000000 00007fff5e7c5908
0x0000000002dca330:   0000000002dcc230 0000000000000000
0x0000000002dca340:   0000000002dcb0c0 0000000002dca960
0x0000000002dca350:   0000000002dcb0c0 00007fff5e7c587b
0x0000000002dca360:   0000000002dcc230 0000000002dce7b0
0x0000000002dca370:   0000b44f6781abf0 0000000002dca568
0x0000000002dca380:   0000000002dcc230 00007fff5e801e89
0x0000000002dca390:   00007fff4f248594 0000000002dcb6d8
0x0000000002dca3a0:   0000000000000100 0000000000000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007fff77b0a1c8)
0x00007fff77b0a1a8:   49 8b d1 44 0f 47 c0 44 89 44 24 38 49 c1 e0 03
0x00007fff77b0a1b8:   e8 af eb 04 00 48 8d 4c 24 20 ff 15 18 05 0a 00
0x00007fff77b0a1c8:   48 8b 8c 24 c0 00 00 00 48 33 cc e8 88 b4 04 00
0x00007fff77b0a1d8:   48 81 c4 d8 00 00 00 c3 83 64 24 38 00 eb d6 cc 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000f8aaf0 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000002dcc230 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000002ccd800
RCX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000f768d0 is an unknown value
RSP=0x0000000002dca2b0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000002ccd800
RBP=0x0000000002dca960 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000002ccd800
RSI=0x0000000002dcc860 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000002ccd800
RDI=0x0000000002dcb0c0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000002ccd800
R8 =0x0000000200000000 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000100000002 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000000002 is an unknown value
R11=0x0000000100000002 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000002dca408 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000002ccd800
R13=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R14=0x0000000002dcb6d8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000002ccd800
R15=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x0000000002cd0000,0x0000000002dd0000],  sp=0x0000000002dca2b0,  free space=1000k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0x2a1c8]
C  [MSVCR120_CLR0400.dll+0x61e89]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x95c53]
C  [clr.dll+0x12dbd]
C  [clr.dll+0x12b5a]
C  [clr.dll+0x84c9]
C  [clr.dll+0x3055]
C  0x00007ffeef7d3525

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  mx.com.solser.service.PrinterService.imprimirPDF(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I+0
j  mx.com.solser.service.PrinterService.printAndGetCode(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Integer;+42
j  mx.com.solser.principal.RunnerPrinter.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+19
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x000000001e8d6000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12780, stack(0x000000001f400000,0x000000001f500000)]
  0x000000001e834800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11660, stack(0x000000001f300000,0x000000001f400000)]
  0x000000001e836800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3868, stack(0x000000001f200000,0x000000001f300000)]
  0x000000001e82c000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6892, stack(0x000000001f100000,0x000000001f200000)]
  0x000000001e828800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8720, stack(0x000000001f000000,0x000000001f100000)]
  0x000000001e827000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10052, stack(0x000000001ef00000,0x000000001f000000)]
  0x000000001e824000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11764, stack(0x000000001ee00000,0x000000001ef00000)]
  0x0000000002ecd800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10644, stack(0x000000001ec00000,0x000000001ed00000)]
  0x0000000002ec4800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14240, stack(0x000000001e700000,0x000000001e800000)]
=>0x0000000002ccd800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=12584, stack(0x0000000002cd0000,0x0000000002dd0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x000000001c909800 VMThread [stack: 0x000000001e600000,0x000000001e700000] [id=7548]
  0x000000001e8d9800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x000000001f500000,0x000000001f600000] [id=10956]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 76288K, used 2621K [0x000000076b300000, 0x0000000770800000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 65536K, 4% used [0x000000076b300000,0x000000076b58f5e8,0x000000076f300000)
  from space 10752K, 0% used [0x000000076fd80000,0x000000076fd80000,0x0000000770800000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x000000076f300000,0x000000076f300000,0x000000076fd80000)
 ParOldGen       total 175104K, used 0K [0x00000006c1800000, 0x00000006cc300000, 0x000000076b300000)
  object space 175104K, 0% used [0x00000006c1800000,0x00000006c1800000,0x00000006cc300000)
 Metaspace       used 2607K, capacity 4490K, committed 4864K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 284K, capacity 386K, committed 512K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000012290000,0x0000000012a90000] byte_map_base: 0x000000000ec84000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x0000000063f1a6d0
 Begin Bits: [0x00000000137e0000, 0x0000000017780000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000017780000, 0x000000001b720000)

Polling page: 0x0000000000f30000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=1104Kb max_used=1111Kb free=244655Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002ed0000, 0x0000000003140000, 0x0000000011ed0000]
 total_blobs=257 nmethods=26 adapters=145
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 0.065 Thread 0x000000001e834800 nmethod 20 0x0000000002fe15d0 code [0x0000000002fe1780, 0x0000000002fe1eb8]
Event: 0.065 Thread 0x000000001e834800   22       3       java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder::append (50 bytes)
Event: 0.065 Thread 0x000000001e834800 nmethod 22 0x0000000002fe2290 code [0x0000000002fe2460, 0x0000000002fe2bb8]
Event: 0.065 Thread 0x000000001e834800   24       3       java.lang.String::indexOf (7 bytes)
Event: 0.065 Thread 0x000000001e82c000 nmethod 23 0x0000000002fe5b90 code [0x0000000002fe5ce0, 0x0000000002fe5db8]
Event: 0.065 Thread 0x000000001e834800 nmethod 24 0x0000000002fe5790 code [0x0000000002fe5900, 0x0000000002fe5b08]
Event: 0.068 Thread 0x000000001e834800   25       3       java.lang.StringBuilder::append (8 bytes)
Event: 0.068 Thread 0x000000001e834800 nmethod 25 0x0000000002fe4c10 code [0x0000000002fe4d80, 0x0000000002fe4f08]
Event: 0.069 Thread 0x000000001e834800   26       3       java.lang.System::getSecurityManager (4 bytes)
Event: 0.069 Thread 0x000000001e834800 nmethod 26 0x0000000002fe4910 code [0x0000000002fe4a60, 0x0000000002fe4bb0]

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (2 events):
Event: 0.026 Thread 0x0000000002ccd800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BII)Ljava/lang/Class; name or signature does not match> (0x000000076b307c78) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u112\7884\hotspot\
Event: 0.026 Thread 0x0000000002ccd800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.prefetchRead(Ljava/lang/Object;J)V name or signature does not match> (0x000000076b307f60) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u112\7884\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.068 loading class java/lang/Class$MethodArray
Event: 0.068 loading class java/lang/Class$MethodArray done
Event: 0.068 loading class mx/com/solser/exception/PrinterException
Event: 0.068 loading class mx/com/solser/exception/PrinterException done
Event: 0.068 loading class java/lang/Void
Event: 0.069 loading class java/lang/Void done
Event: 0.069 loading class mx/com/solser/service/PrinterService
Event: 0.069 loading class mx/com/solser/service/PrinterService done
Event: 0.069 loading class java/lang/ClassLoaderHelper
Event: 0.069 loading class java/lang/ClassLoaderHelper done


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff70acc0000 - 0x00007ff70acf7000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin\javaw.exe
0x00007fff7ad90000 - 0x00007fff7af52000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007fff795b0000 - 0x00007fff7965d000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007fff77ae0000 - 0x00007fff77cbd000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007fff786d0000 - 0x00007fff78776000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007fff791f0000 - 0x00007fff7928d000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007fff78510000 - 0x00007fff7856b000     C:\Windows\system32\sechost.dll
0x00007fff789e0000 - 0x00007fff78b06000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007fff78da0000 - 0x00007fff78eee000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x00007fff787e0000 - 0x00007fff78965000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x00007fff72150000 - 0x00007fff723c4000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.10240.17184_none_f41d7a705752bce6\COMCTL32.dll
0x00007fff7ac00000 - 0x00007fff7ac36000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x00007fff78570000 - 0x00007fff786cc000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x0000000063fa0000 - 0x0000000064072000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x0000000063700000 - 0x0000000063f9a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007fff79660000 - 0x00007fff79668000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007fff6eb30000 - 0x00007fff6eb39000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007fff75c70000 - 0x00007fff75c93000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007fff73ed0000 - 0x00007fff73eda000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x00007fff78970000 - 0x00007fff789d9000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007fff78500000 - 0x00007fff78508000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x0000000001340000 - 0x000000000136c000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x00007fff78400000 - 0x00007fff78444000     C:\Windows\system32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x00007fff76130000 - 0x00007fff76157000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x00000000636f0000 - 0x00000000636ff000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x00000000636c0000 - 0x00000000636e9000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\bin\java.dll
0x00000000636a0000 - 0x00000000636b6000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x00007fff79670000 - 0x00007fff7ab93000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x00007fff77d20000 - 0x00007fff78349000     C:\Windows\system32\windows.storage.dll
0x00007fff78f70000 - 0x00007fff791ec000     C:\Windows\system32\combase.dll
0x00007fff78f10000 - 0x00007fff78f61000     C:\Windows\system32\shlwapi.dll
0x00007fff777b0000 - 0x00007fff777bf000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x00007fff77850000 - 0x00007fff77903000     C:\Windows\system32\shcore.dll
0x00007fff77800000 - 0x00007fff7784a000     C:\Windows\system32\powrprof.dll
0x00007fff777e0000 - 0x00007fff777f3000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x00007fff6afe0000 - 0x00007fff6b012000     E:\WSImpresion\PrintService\CppSymetryBusModuloImpresora.dll
0x00007fff6afb0000 - 0x00007fff6afd2000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VCRUNTIME140D.dll
0x00007fff6ac20000 - 0x00007fff6addb000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ucrtbased.dll
0x00007fff67960000 - 0x00007fff679c8000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\mscoree.dll
0x00007fff6aeb0000 - 0x00007fff6afa6000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140D.dll
0x00007fff62460000 - 0x00007fff624f8000     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
0x00007fff4ee40000 - 0x00007fff4f79c000     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
0x00007fff5e7a0000 - 0x00007fff5e897000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCR120_CLR0400.dll
0x00007fff4d9a0000 - 0x00007fff4ee38000     C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\mscorlib\fa8eef6f6cb67c660d71e15c5cad71b5\mscorlib.ni.dll
0x00007fff5e690000 - 0x00007fff5e795000     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll
0x00007fff7acb0000 - 0x00007fff7ad72000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x00007fff6ab00000 - 0x00007fff6ac17000     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\diasymreader.dll
0x00007fff79460000 - 0x00007fff795a1000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x00007fff4cdc0000 - 0x00007fff4d992000     C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System\dd13bec6e0f1710a98d6c8745d5d4eb4\System.ni.dll
0x00007fff69fb0000 - 0x00007fff6a13a000     C:\Windows\system32\DBGHELP.DLL
0x00007fff6ae80000 - 0x00007fff6aea5000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dbgcore.DLL

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -XX:+CreateMinidumpOnCrash -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 
java_command: mx.com.solser.principal.RunnerPrinter
java_class_path (initial): E:\WSImpresion\PrintService\bin
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112
PATH=C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin;E:\Software\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;E:\IDE\eclipse;
USERNAME=Green 4
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 10.0 , 64 bit Build 10240 (10.0.10240.17113)

CPU:total 8 (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 42 stepping 7, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, clmul, ht, tsc, tscinvbit

Memory: 4k page, physical 16675216k(9227236k free), swap 17723792k(10648200k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.112-b15) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_112-b15), built on Sep 22 2016 21:31:56 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Thu Mar 09 09:18:39 2017
elapsed time: 0 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I create another C# class and make reference to dll provided by de client, that's all.

the jni4net plugin works fine.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SymetryBusModuloImpresora;

namespace PrinterService {
    public class PrinterService {
            public static int imprimriPDF(string ruta, string archivo) {
            return SymetryBusModuloImpresora.cImpresora.ImprimirPDF(ruta, archivo);
        }
    }
}
```

After, is all like jni4net plugin documentation.
1.- proxygen 
2.- build.cmd
3.- Load generated dll
3.- put jars in classpath